# Why doesn't the paragraph element overflow everything including the body

Tags: html, css, overflow, paragraph

Hi so I've made a circle image and a paragraph page but for some reason the paragraph element overflows through everything including it's parent and the body element. Does anyone know why this happens?

## Explanation for being a "duplicate" question

This is not a duplicate question in my opinion because the other question's (which supposedly is the same as this one) answer doesn't include `tranform: scale(0.5);`. But I need scaling for my own image. I don't use lorem picsum images in my real project. But If you check the other question's answer, whilst it is correct, when I scale it down, it causes the entire element to scale down but the I only need the image to scale down. If you add the code `transform: scale(0.5);` to the other question, you'll see it'll just look out of shape. So I think this question need to be reopened because of the fact that **it is not a duplicate.** And I don't understand the relation between these two questions. One is about the text not being aligned but this question is about the text overflowing.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3000px;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

img.boat-main {
  float: left;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 116vw;
  height: 116vw;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%) scale(0.5);
  object-position: center -150px;
  shape-outside: circle(53% at 0 0);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}


.boat-main-description {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/900/1600" class="boat-main">

        <div class="boat-main-description">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ullamcorper non lacus at pellentesque. Proin leo sapien, placerat id ultrices et, gravida sit amet quam. Cras pretium, augue id dapibus viverra, risus erat sagittis quam, vitae placerat augue lacus in nulla. Maecenas rutrum hendrerit arcu. Cras eleifend malesuada imperdiet. Duis pharetra est et tempor lacinia. Vivamus ex mauris, viverra eu posuere eu, finibus non ante. Nullam tristique nisl a velit interdum, in ornare nulla convallis. Suspendisse odio dui, vestibulum id diam non, blandit efficitur odio. Proin facilisis magna non justo semper, ut finibus tellus volutpat. Pellentesque lobortis felis eget faucibus tempor. Nullam eleifend quam vel turpis eleifend efficitur. Nulla sollicitudin ultricies augue nec luctus.
          </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: as I said in your previous question: you are adding a lot of useless styles and together they are creating issue. Why did you modify my code? it was working well. I don't see why adding those transform and using big width/height values

Comment: @TemaniAfif because I needed to use ```transform: scale(0.5);``` to my image and I couldn't find a way without making the size bigger, that's why I used ```transfrom: translate();```. If you try to add scaling to your solution to my problem with the previous question you'll see that the entire element scales instead of the image. That's why in my first try I tried adding a parent element so that only the image scales

Comment: and why you need to use scale()? describe why it's need because I don't see why and don't repeat the same question. Edit your old question to add more detail. You are not obliged to accept an answer if doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not using lorem picsum images in my real project I needed the scale my own image but I though I didn't need to post my image here as it's my business

Comment: I'm reopening, but can you improve the wording a bit? It took me almost 5 minutes to realize that you're concerned about the overflow into the **parent** element and not into the image (which isn't the case for the example). The negation in the title even contradicts the question body (*doesn't*) and it certainly doesn't overflow into *everything*. It merely overflows into the parent on the right.